# Select element and scroll bar when options popup

Tags: html, css

I have a `select` with more than 50 `option`s. now when i click on `select`, options will popup and go out of the page without any scroll bar.

So i'm not able to select and see more that 20 options.
how to force `select` element to have vertical scroll bar if `option`s are more than 15 or 20 items ?

I don't want to use `size=?` because it expand my select box vertically.

Comment: What you want is actually the default behavior. Make sure you don't have some weird CSS rules going on.

Comment: i checked it using firebug, there is no style assigned to it

Comment: Can you construct a test case on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: -1 Show your code and reproduce your problem in a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). Here is a a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bw7HT/) of a select box with 235 options and the problems you refer to do not occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check so the selectbox is created correctly `<select></select>`and every option is constructed like

```
<option value="value">option name</option>
```

within the selectbox.